# ThreadPool/Executor with max working threads at a same time

Tags: java

Does Java have a thread pool that will limit maximum number of concurrently executing tasks not including tasks that are waiting for IO or waiting for notification on Object.wait()?

If no, is it possible to write it by myself, to allow only specified number of threads to run and when one waits for IO, start another task and when IO will be possible, thread will be allowed to run only when other completed.

Comment: What if all your waiting threads are simultaneously released from waiting for IO. Bang?

Comment: Then one of them should be released to continue.

Comment: But blocking against IO is at the OS/kernel level, not the JVM level. As far as the JVM is concerned the `Thread` is in a `RUNNING` state...

Comment: OK, so maybe counting blocked on IO as running but not counting threads Object.wait().

Comment: Isn't that just a [`Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)?

Comment: Semaphore could be used with unlimited number of threads to limit the number. Of course instead of using Object.wait() the tasks should use semaphore acquire/release methods. That is something that I would like to not use directly. Especially that I can have multiple monitor objects and notify only subgroup when needed, not all threads.